What are the consequences or risks of signing a document with a future date?
I know you shouldn't past-date something (e.g. date for yesterday), but what are the consequences/risks of writing a future date on a document?
In my specific instance, I'm getting a bridge loan out of state. The documents are being sent to me to sign and then returned to the bank. This is all happening a few days before the loan is needed to ensure that it happens in time. However, the documents will be dated a few days after I actually sign them.
I'd prefer answers that discuss the question more generally though.

Why would the documents be future dated?  Loans are processed all the time where one side of the transaction signs all their documents one day and the other side of the transaction signs all their documents another day.  And sometimes the loan disburses on another day.

@JustinCave A few days extra interest on something the size of a home is easily hundreds of dollars.

@user71659 - True, but I'm not sure how that is relevant.  If money is being moved from one account to another, it matters when that money disburses which has no relationship to when documents were signed.  Sure most of the time documents are signed on the same day the money is paid but you can certainly sign documents in advance.  Interest wouldn't start accumulating until the disbursement date.

Do you mean you signed them in the future (so you sign today and write next weeks date), or do you mean you signed them with todays date, but the contract says something about the future (lets say: first working day is the next Monday)?

I had anticipated a case where signature lines had a "signature and date" format where the date would be hand written beside the signature. What ended up happening was that the paperwork had effective dates explicitly listed through the document and at no point was a date filled in by hand except on one page for the notary. That one page made it clear that it was the date the paperwork was signed, not the effective date of the loan.


what are the consequences/risks of writing a future date on a
document?

In the context of the OP this is harmless.
Indeed, the person signing them can probably revoke those signatures prior to closing on the date shown on the documents, if something comes up in the meantime.

I'd prefer answers that discuss the question more generally though.

The most common time this comes up is when a check is presented to someone as payment with a date after it is written. In that situation there are potential  risks.
The intent when this is done is usually to prevent the check from being drawn upon until the date of the check, with the date of the check often being someone's payday. When this is done in this way, it is often called "payday lending."
The main risk in that scenario is that the person receiving the check will, intentionally or just accidentally, deposit the check before the date on the check, when there are insufficient funds in the check writer's checking account to pay for the check. This leaves the person to whom the check was written unpaid (although they can resubmit the check again to the bank after the first not sufficient funds rejection) and will typically cause the check account holder to incur a bounced check fee.
Generally speaking, the bank is not legally required to confirm that the date shown on the check has actually arrived when it is deposited, so this requires that the person writing the check trust the person to whom it is given to delay depositing it.

I understand "Payday Lending" to be somewhat different - a loan that is very short term; expected to be repaid when the borrower next receives a salary.

Writing a later date on a check is often or usually called a "postdated check." "Payday lending" is definitely a different concept; I am not familiar enough to know if postdated checks are used in the implementation thereof.

@stannius The usual way that payday lending is conducted is with post-dated checks.

You were correct about the ability to revoke the signatures. In fact, there was a specific page dedicated to ensuring I knew that I could and how to do it.
